# How to create a script to automate link exchange in HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I'm performing maintenance on a system that has hundreds of links on one page as follows:

```html
<li> Revista alvo <a href="http://exemplo.com"> http://exemplo.com </a> </li>
```

Note that there is text outside the `a` tag. What I want to do, put this text inside the `a` tag with your supposed href, the example above would look like this:

```html
<li> <a href="http://exemplo.com"> Revista alvo </a> </li>
```

I'm doing this change in hand but there are hundreds and hundreds of links, which makes the task tiring. Does anyone have any idea how I can script to do this? It can be in any language, `PHP`,`JS` etc.

Comment: Depending on the way the rest of the document looks, you  can do this with existing tools as well, like Notepad++ or maybe [fart](http://fart-it.sourceforge.net/). Question lacks the context needed to verify this solution.

Comment: Is the text in HTML format?

Comment: You can probably use the feature of your text editor to find and replace using [regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info). If you have trouble writing the regex, write a specific question about it that includes the regex you tried so far.

Comment: @SaidbakR yes, text is in HTML

Comment: @RoryO'Kane help a example, please!

Comment: Have you made any attempt to do this yourself (programatically), how far did you get?

Comment: An example of a regex is finding `start (\w+) end` and replacing with `word: $1`, which would change “start hello end” into “word: hello”. Your text editor such as [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) or [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) can find and replace text with this syntax. To learn how to write regexes like this, go to [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you regarded, the text is HTML format, so you can easily, edit the HTML file and use [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) to apply changes to the [dom](/questions/tagged/dom) like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<ul id="linksList">
  <li> Revista alvo <a href="http://exemplo.com"> http://exemplo.com </a> </li>
  <li> Revista alvo <a href="http://exemplo.com"> http://exemplo.com </a> </li>
  <li> Revista alvo <a href="http://exemplo.com"> http://exemplo.com </a> </li>
  <li> Revista alvo <a href="http://exemplo.com"> http://exemplo.com </a> </li>
  <li> Revista alvo <a href="http://exemplo.com"> http://exemplo.com </a> </li>
  <li> Revista alvo <a href="http://exemplo.com"> http://exemplo.com </a> </li>
  <li> Revista alvo <a href="http://exemplo.com"> http://exemplo.com </a> </li>
  <li> Revista alvo <a href="http://exemplo.com"> http://exemplo.com </a> </li>
  <li> Revista alvo <a href="http://exemplo.com"> http://exemplo.com </a> </li>
  <li> Revista alvo <a href="http://exemplo.com"> http://exemplo.com </a> </li>
  <li> Revista alvo <a href="http://exemplo10.com"> http://exemplo.com </a> </li>

  </ul>
  <a href="#" id="changeIt">Change</a>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){     
      $("#changeIt").click(function(){
        $("#linksList li").each(function(){
          txt = $(this).text().split(' http://')[0].trim();
          lnk = $(this).children('a').text(txt)
          $(this).html(lnk)
        })
      })
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The edit should include,

1. include jquery
2. give the `ul` or `ol` that contains the `li` an id
3. use the code supplied in the latter `script` tag which consider the given id to the list is `linksList`
4. HTML link with id `changeIt` to invoke the code.

[This is an Online demo](http://jsbin.com/dovaqepehu/edit?html,console,output)